# Caching a static Database table in Django

Tags: python, django, caching

I have a Django web application that is currently live and receiving a lot of queries. I am looking for ways to optimize its performance and one area that can be improved is how it interacts with its database.

In its current state, each request to a particular view loads an entire database table into a pandas dataframe, against which queries are done. This table consists of over 55,000 rows of text data (co-ordinates mostly).

To avoid needless queries, I have been advised to cache the database into memory and have it be cached upon the first time its loaded. This will remove some overhead on the DB side of things. I've never used this feature of Django before so I am a bit lost.

The Django [manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/) does not seem to have a concrete implementation of what I want to do. Would it be a good idea to just store the entire table in memory or would storing it in a file be a better idea?

Comment: I predict this question will be flagged as too broad, but I can suggest you to start with https://github.com/Suor/django-cacheops and then google further when you will be concerned with what exactly you want

Comment: You can also try [django cachalot](https://github.com/BertrandBordage/django-cachalot). It's real easy to setup and it does exactly what you want: saves the query on first request in memory and later just gets it from there.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and [django-cache-machine](https://github.com/django-cache-machine/django-cache-machine) worked like a charm. It uses the Django caching features to cache the results of your queries. It is very easy to set up (assuming you have already configured Django's cache backend):

```
pip install django-cache-machine
```

Then in the model you want to cache:

```
from caching.base import CachingManager, CachingMixin

class MyModel(CachingMixin, models.Model):
    objects = CachingManager()
```

And that's it, your queries will be cached.